# How to fix 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, anaconda, spyder

I just installed  Spyder (Python 3.8) and in the Anaconda Prompt, i installed OpenCV, however while running the following statements:

`import cv2`
`face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')`

I receive as error: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'.

Let me tell you that i've already downloaded 'haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml' file.
Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: try face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalcatface') or verfiy the path of  haarcascade_frontalcatface file

Comment: I tried both of them, but none of these works :/

Comment: what version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version '4.4.0'

Comment: do print(cv2) and report the output here

Comment: If I am not mistaken Haar Cascade is not included in OpenCV 4.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Did you install the latest version of OpenCV or the version which actually contains the implementation of this CascadeClassifier?
Maybe, you could try running `conda update opencv` and see if it resolves the problem or not.

Comment: I tried it , and what i received in the  Anaconda Prompt:

Requirement already up-to-date: opencv-python in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.4.0.44)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.5)